# Multi-route mobile networking - can wireguard solve this problem?

Tags: linux, wireguard

I have a fleet of vehicles which will have Linux-based routers, with multiple upstream routes.  These routes work intermittently due to coverage of different technologies.

Can I use Wireguard to make tunnels over these links and rely on Wireguard to choose a working link for each packet?

(It's important, for TCP continuity, that packets from the router all arrive at the centre with the same (Wireguard) IP address.)

If so, do I need one wgX interface for each link, or does it handle all this magically?

Or do I need to use a routing protocol, such as OSPF or BGP?

Comment: Unfortunately, your routers and Wireguard are off-topic here as hosts/servers. You could try to ask about those on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Most VPNs do NOT like the client endpoints changing address. (it'll look like a replay attack.) But otherwise, there's nothing stopping a client from reconnected when the address changes.

Comment: @Ricky Wireguard's frontpage reads: "It is even capable of roaming between IP addresses, just like Mosh."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use Wireguard to make tunnels over these links and rely on Wireguard to choose a working link for each packet?

You could use a VPN technology to enable continuous addressing *if* that VPN technology allows *seamless roaming*. We cannot recommend any products over others here.

> If so, do I need one wgX interface for each link, or does it handle all this magically?

Implementation depends on the actual product, but normally all that is handled by the VPN endpoint/remote access server.

> Or do I need to use a routing protocol, such as OSPF or BGP?

Far too complicated, just make it work on the server. Even if you had a whole network behind each remote mobile router, you'd assign subnets statically.